# visual studio 2010 and entity framework 5.0, can I use it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Well, really I wanted to update the 4.1 version of entity framework, so in tools-->library package manager-->package manager I use this command:

Install-Package EntityFramework

Then the update started. I saw a message saying that the version 5 is installed. I my project folder I can see two foloders, one with the net4 lib and other with the net5 library.

However, in my references in the project, the 4.1 was replaced with the 4.4, not with the 5.0 version, so I would like to know if I can use the 5.0 version or only the 4.4 version. If I only can use the 4.4 version, why is installed the 5.0 version? I know that the 5.0 version is installed because if I try to install again entity framework through the package manager, I get the following message:

"'EntityFramework 5.0.0' already installed."

Thanks.

Comment: If you mean for section in webconfig than EF 5 has 4.4 so your project is using EF 5 but without some features that version for .net 4.5 has.

Comment: Is this question really related to Visual Studio 2010? If so, could you please add an according tag? Is there a specific reason for you to not use VS2012? If so, I recommend to mention that in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Entity framework will reference 4.4 when you're targeting .NET 4.0

See [this blog](http://brice-lambson.blogspot.com/2012/10/unicorn-myths-debunked-entity-framework.html).

> The 4.4 comes from the assembly version of EntityFramework.dll when
>   you install EntityFramework 5.0 into a project that targets .NET
>   Framework 4.0. This is merely a side effect of how the runtime loads
>   and binds to assemblies, and in no way reflects the version of the
>   product.

Comment: so I have for example the performance of EF5 although I can't use other options such as enum?

Comment: From the [Release info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/05/15/ef5-release-candidate-available-on-nuget.aspx) (look in the compatability section) : Some features are only available when writing an application that targets .NET 4.5. This includes enum support, spatial data types, table-valued functions and the performance improvements. If you are targeting .NET 4.0 you still get all the bug fixes and other minor improvements.

Comment: @Daimroc FYI, the [nightly builds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/09/17/ef-nightly-builds-available.aspx) of EF6 have support for enums, etc. on .NET 4.0. Keep in mind these are pre-prerelease versions of EF.